Problems with cors
I'm developping an app using Ionic Angular which has front (localhost 8100) and back (localhost 3700), but when i try to do a fetch to get some items from the database, i got an error that says:

"Cross-origin request blocked: The same-origin policy does not allow
reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3700/api/productid/1.
(Reason: CORS request failed.) Status code: (null)."

The problem is that i've installed the cors package, and then i've imported it via
var cors = require('cors') and app.use(cors()); , so I really dont understand what else to do


var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors') //cors
var app = express();
app.use(cors());



also tried:


app.use(
  cors({
    allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"], // you can change the headers
    exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], // you can change the headers
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false
  });
);



And my Angular service (front):


import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductosService {

  private urlApi = 'https://localhost:3700/api/productoid/1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData() : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(this.urlApi);
  }

}





import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductosService } from '../services/productos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  data: any[] = [];

  constructor(private productosService: ProductosService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.llenarData();
  }

  llenarData(){
    this.productosService.getData().subscribe(data => 
      {this.data = data;
      console.log(this.data)

    })
  }

  

}



Used multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera).
As expected, when I try to call the backend using postman I get the correct response.
--------edit 1--------
Like someone said in the comment section, i've tried to add "x-requested-with"to "allowedHeaders":


  var express = require('express');
  const cors = require('cors');
  var app = express();
  
  app.use(
    cors({
      allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type", "x-requested-with"], 
      exposedHeaders: ["authorization"], 
      origin: "*",
      methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
      preflightContinue: false
    }));



But the error persists
I forgot to add that my app has an authentication form to access a user account, maybe this info will help

Can you push the code to any public git repo and share? Also sharing the network logs in useful. You can export the network log with this
https://ibb.co/rvM34VG

The problem likely stems from the fact that RxJS includes a X-Requested-With header in its requests and that your CORS config doesn't list the header name in question as allowed. Try changing allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "Content-Type"] to allowedHeaders: ["authorization", "content-type", "x-requested-with"].

Try setting Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded when you send the request (on Angular side).
